# is it possible for an app to insert an event at a specific date in Facebook Timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Is it possible for an app to insert an event at a specific date (in the past) in Facebook Timeline?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's available now but I *think* this will be implemented soon! +1

Comment: Above your update status bar is a couple icons to add relationships, events etc into your timline.

Comment: i need to do this programmatically from within the app via the OpenGraph API, not manually as you suggest.

Comment: Oh, that is beyond me.  I haven't played with OpenGraph API too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can publish an action on behalf of a user at a specific point in time by setting the action's "start_time" property to a date in the past.  For more info, see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/#timestamps

Comment: thanks for the link (it should be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/). It has the information i was looking for.